# How to perform forloop in node js

Tags: node.js, express

Acoording to the data available ui should get 2 reults but getting only one since i put res.send in the looop so it is getting ended ,can anyone help me out please.......

```
exports.getrequestsdetails = function(req, res) {
    var params = req.params;
    console.log(params)
    var record = db.collection('requests');
    var item = {
        "sent_id": params.id,
        "status": 1
    }
    record.find(item).toArray((err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            return
        }
        if (result) {
            for (var i in result) {
                var id = result[i].recieved_id;
                var profile = db.collection('profile');
                profile.find({
                    '_id': new ObjectId(id)
                }).toArray((err, resp) => {
                    if (err) {
                        return
                    }
                    if (resp) {
                        console.log(resp);
                    } else {}
                });
            }
            res.send(resp);
        } //end of if loop
        else {
            response = {
                status: 'fail',
                data: []
            };
        }

    });

}
```

Comment: What is the items in list array?

Comment: Hi abdulbarik,i edited my code

Comment: with added res.send(resp); i am getting error resp not defined

Comment: but i can see my required data in console for console.log(resp)

Comment: Since its out of scope

Comment: What database interface are you using?  The "right" answer here is to use promises.  If your database already has a promise interface, you should use that in conjunction with other promise-based flow controls.  If your database does not have a promise interface, then you should promisify the methods you're using and then use promise-based controls.

Comment: mongodb..........

Comment: I am not sure about that can u help me..............

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in getting the profiles. You are using mongodb's find which is **asynchronous**. Therefore in your `for` cycle you start fetching the profiles, but then you send out the `res.send` well before the fetching of the profiles is finished.

The call back from `profile.find(...` will be executed **after** the `res.send`. Apart from this, the `resp` variable is inside the find callback and you are trying to `res.send` it outside.

To deal with this, either you use **async** or **promises**. See the below code that uses promises.

```
var Promise = require('bluebird')

exports.getrequestsdetails = function(req, res) {
    var params = req.params;
    console.log(params)
    var record = db.collection('requests');
    var item = {
        "sent_id": params.id,
        "status": 1
    }

    record.find(item).toArray((err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            return
        }
        if (result) {

            var profiles_to_get = []
            var profiles = []

            for (var i in result) {
                var id = result[i].recieved_id;
                profiles_to_get.push(get_profile(id, profiles))
            }

            Promise.all(profiles_to_get)
                .then(() => {
                    res.send(profiles);
                })
        } //end of if loop
        else {
            response = {
                status: 'fail',
                data: []
            };
        }

    });

    function get_profile (id, profiles) {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            var profile = db.collection('profile');
                profile.find({
                    '_id': new ObjectId(id)
                }).toArray((err, resp) => {
                    if (err) {
                        reject(err)
                        return
                    }
                    if (resp) {
                        profiles.push(resp)
                        resolve()
                    } else {
                        reject()
                    }
                });
        })
    }

}
```

How this works is that it creates a list of profiles to find and stores it in the `var profiles_to_get = []`. The you use `Promise.All(profiles_to_get)` which will let you do stuff after all the profiles have been fetched.

Comment: does it tell you a line number?

Comment: That is fixed ,nw it says promise.All is not  a function

Comment: sorry, should be Promise.all without the capital A

Comment: Thanks a lot finally its working,but is such a long method is realyy reqired here,cant we do it with array push

Comment: Cool. You could try to to optimize it a little to make it more readable and shorter, however there is little way around the fact that you are doing nested asynchronous calls in a loop and you have to detect when all are finished and send the response then.

Comment: Anyhow thanks again,a small change i want the data in this format {status:"success",data:profiles}

Comment: with this   if (resp) {
                        response = {status:"success",data:resp}
                        profiles.push(response)
                        resolve()        i am getting like this

Comment: [
  {
    "status": "success",
    "data": [
      {
        "_id": "57dfcddf1ad7cf658860926e",
        "firstname": "rahul"
        
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "status": "success",
    "data": [
      {
        "_id": "57dfcdf61ad7cf658860926f",
        "firstname": "Dhoni"
      }
    ]
  }
]

Comment: i want like this    [
  {
    "status": "success",
    "data": [
      {
        "_id": "57dfcddf1ad7cf658860926e",
        "firstname": "rahul",
        "lastname": "dravid",
        "profilename": "Rahul dravid",
   
      }
 
      {
        "_id": "57dfcdf61ad7cf658860926f",
        "firstname": "Dhoni",
        "lastname": "MS",
        "profilename": "MS Dhoni",
    
      }
    ]
  }
]

Comment: get rid of the status for each profie: `profiles.push(resp.data)` and return status when sending the response: `res.send({status: 'success', data: profiles});`

Comment: with added code i am getting this,..................{
  "status": "success",
  "data": [
    null,
    null
  ]
}

Answer (score 1):

You can send only one response back to a request.

Define a variable outside the for loop, append records to it and then send it after the for loop has ended.

```
exports.getrequestsdetails = function(req, res) {
var params = req.params;
console.log(params)
var record = db.collection('requests');
var item = {
    "sent_id": params.id,
    "status": 1
}

var resList = [];

record.find(item).toArray((err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            return
        }
        if (result) {
            for (var i in result) {
                var id = result[i].recieved_id;
                var profile = db.collection('profile');
                profile.find({
                    '_id': new ObjectId(id)
                }).toArray((err, resp) => {
                        if (err) {
                            return
                        }
                        if (resp) {
                           console.log(resp);
                           resList[i] = resp;
                        }
                        else{
                      }
                });
            }
        }//end of if loop
        else {
             resList = {
                status: 'fail',
                data: []
              };
         }
        res.send(resList);
       });
```

Comment: It wont going work, how can you get `i` value out of it's scope

Comment: It is within scope now.

Comment: Anish,i am getting empty object as res but  i can see res in o/p

Answer (score 1):

You can `push` all the `resp` in `list` array  and send after completing `loop`.

Like this:

```
    exports.getrequestsdetails = function(req, res) {
    var params = req.params;
    console.log(params);

    var record = db.collection('requests');
    var item = {
        "sent_id": params.id,
        "status": 1
    };

    record.find(item).toArray((err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            return err;
        }
        if (result) {
            var list = [];
            for (var i in result) {
                var id = result[i].recieved_id;
                var profile = db.collection('profile');
                profile.find({
                    '_id': new ObjectId(id)
                }).toArray((err, resp) => {
                    if (err) {
                        return err;
                    }
                    else{
                        list.push(resp);
                        console.log(resp);
                        if(i===result[result.length-1]){
                             res.send(list);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

        } //end of if loop
        else {
            response = {
                status: 'fail',
                data: []
            };
        }

    });
};
```

Hope this work for you

Comment: but where should i have to keep res.send(resp).?

Comment: It's up to you when you want to send the res?

Comment: Right now it sends after completing the for loop

Comment: Its not woeking

Comment: Can you check the list value before sending it?

Comment: I updated answer and it must be work if you are getting proper value of `resp`

Comment: It is giving the right o/p in console but in send it shows empty array

Comment: still getting the empty array as o/p

Comment: Can you add console.log(list) before res.send() and check the value

Comment: i just put like this     console.log(resp);
                res.send(resp);    and i can see console but not res

Comment: print `list` not `resp` before send see the my above comment

Comment: sorry i am getting anything in console if i put before res.send(resp)

Comment: Did you print `console.log(list)`?

Comment: no way this works. the callback from find is asynchronous so the `res.send` will happen before anything is pushed to the list

Comment: @klp Can you try now

Answer (score 1):

Don't use for loop in asynchronous mode. Use async module instead like below.

```
var async = require('async');
exports.getrequestsdetails = function (req, res) {
    var params = req.params;
    console.log(params)
    var record = db.collection('requests');
    var item = {
        "sent_id": params.id,
        "status": 1
    }
    record.find(item).toArray(function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            return
        }
        if (result) {
            var list = [];
            async.each(result, function (item, cb) {
                var id = item.recieved_id;
                var profile = db.collection('profile');
                profile.findOne({
                    '_id': new ObjectId(id)
                }, function (err, resp) {
                    if (err) {
                        return cb();
                    }
                    if (resp) {
                        list.push(resp);
                        console.log(resp);
                        return  cb();
                    }
                    return cb();
                });
            }, function (err) {
                res.send(list);
            });
        }//end of if loop
        else {
            response = {
                status: 'fail',
                data: []
            };
        }

    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add all the list in to an array and finally send the data after the loop